# Handing high Cardinality features with supervised ratio and weight of evidence

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Say a data set has a categorical feature with high cardinality. Say zipcodes, or cities. Encoding this feature would give hundreds of feature columns. Different approaches such as supervised_ratio, weight of evidence seems to give better performance.

The question is, these supervised_ratio and WOE are to be calculated on the training set, right ? So I get the training set and process it and calcuate the SR and WOE and update the training set with the new values and keep the calculated values to be used in test set as well. But what happens if the test set has zip codes which were not in training set ? when there is no SR or WOE value to be used?  (Practically this is possible if the training data set is not covering all the possible zip codes or if there are only one or two records from certain zip codes which might fall in to either training set or test set).
(Same will happen with encoding approach also)

I am more interested in the question, is SR and/or WOE the recommended way to handle a feature with high cardinality? if so what do we do when there are values in test set which were not in training set? 
If not, what are the recommended ways to handling high cardinality features and which algorithms are more robust to them ? Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to [machine learning, rather than software development](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). You may consider adapting this questions for [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience.SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known problem when applying value-wise transformations to a categorical feature. The most common workaround is to have a set of rules to translate unseen values into values known by your training set.

This can be just a single 'NA' value (or 'others', as another answer is suggesting), or something more elaborate (e.g. in your example, you can map unseen zip codes to the closest know one in the training set).

Another posible solution in some scenarios is to have the model refusing to made a prediction in those cases, and just return an error.

For your second question, there is not really a *recommended* way of encoding high cardinality features (there are many methods and some may work better than others depending on the other features, the target variable, etc..); but what we can recommend you is to implement a few and experiment which one is more effective for your problem. You can consider the preprocessing method used as just another parameter in your learning algorithm.

Comment: Thank You for the answer

Answer (score 2):

That's a great question, thanks for asking!

When approaching this kind of problem of handle a feature with high cardinality, like zip codes, I keep in my training set just the most frequent ones and put all others in new category "others", then I calculate their WOE or any metric.

If some unseen zip code are found the test set, they falls to 'others' category. In general, this approach works well in practice.

I hope this nayve solution can help you!

Comment: Thank You for the answer